# How can i get the system calendar settings in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can i get the system calendar settings in java script? because i need to find which day is assigned to First day of week in system calendar settings.

Comment: use this code can be helpful for you `var curr = new Date; num = curr.getDay();`

Comment: i tried this.. but it gives today's day.. Actually i need to fetch the firstday which is assigned in windows calendar settings.

Comment: maybe this [ https://marcoscaceres.github.io/jsi18n/ ]be helpful.